# New line in handlebar templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, mustache

Using Handlebar/Mustache, I would like to show the Address as follows (with the new lines):

```
{{FirstName}}{{LastName}}
{{Address1}}{{Address2}}
{{City}}
{{State}}
{{Zip}}
```

But the above is always rendered in one line. I tried using \n but it doesn't work. Is it possible to handle new line (\n) in the template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add HTML line breaks to your template:

```
{{FirstName}}{{LastName}}<br/>
{{Address1}}{{Address2}}<br/>
{{City}}<br/>
{{State}}<br/>
{{Zip}}
```

Comment: Duh...that was easy. Thank you :)